# Guppy install in Python 3.11 fails because of missing longintrepr.h file

Tags: python, pip, guppy

Operating System: Windows
I try:

```
pip install guppy3
```

It runs successfully at first but fatally fails towards the end.
The error message is:

```
Collecting guppy3
  Using cached guppy3-3.1.2.tar.gz (335 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: guppy3
  Building wheel for guppy3 (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [95 lines of output]

     //so long so i delete it

      bitset.c
      src/sets/bitset.c(7): fatal error C1083: 無法開啟包含檔案: 'longintrepr.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

By the way I have all ready update
wheel 0.38.4
pip   23.0.1
setuptools  67.6.0

I really have no clue...

Hope someone who can help me to fix this error!

Comment: https://github.com/zhuyifei1999/guppy3/issues/41

Answer (score -1):

I find the solution!I just downgrade my python version to 3.9

Comment: That's a workaround; not a solution.